# How to solve "Cannot add or update child row"

Tags: php, mysql

I have been getting some errors while trying to insert into my database, what mostly concerns me is that i keep getting the error:

> **Cannot add or update child row**

Here is my users table:

```
users:

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| email    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| avatar   | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
| username | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| password | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| about    | text        | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here i have only 1 entry and it is with index 1

And this is my categoryf table:

```
categoryf:

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| descri   | text        | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here i also have 1 entry, and also with index 1

And this is the topic category:

```
topic:

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| user_id  | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| avatar   | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
| title    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| body     | text        | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Where `c_id(category_id)` and `user_id` are foreign keys to the tables `categoryf` and `user`

This is the form i use:

```
 <form method="post" action="create.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Наслов</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Вашата Дискусија</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="post_text" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
            <script>CKEDITOR.replace('post_text');</script>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Категорија</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category">
              <?php foreach(Categoryf_id() as $category) : ?>
              <option><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ;?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-primary">Креирајте Дискусија</button></a>
        </form>
```

Where Categoryf_id is:

```
function Categoryf_id()
{
$db = new Database();

//Create Query Category name
$query="SELECT * FROM categoryf";

//Run Query Category name
$row=$db->select($query);

return $row;
}
```

And finally my Post function:

```
function Post()
{

$db=new Database();

if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['title']);
$post_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['post_text']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['category']);
}
$query= "INSERT INTO topic
        (category_id, user_id, title, body) 
    VALUES('$category', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '$title', '$post_text')";

$insert_row = $db->insert($query);
}
```

I know that my query is correct, because i used it in phpmyadmin to add a topic, where is used the id's as just 1, but here i get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: category in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-    Wizard/helpers/query.php on line 132

Notice: Undefined variable: title in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/query.php on line 132

Notice: Undefined variable: post_text in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/query.php on line 132
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`PHPWizard`.`topic`, CONSTRAINT `topic_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categoryf` (`id`))47
```

I even tried to remove the foreign key checks with `mysql_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');`, with no luck.

I searched other Questions on Stack Overflow, also with no luck.

What is causing this problem and how can i fix it?

Also i apologize if this is such a long post, but i think i needed to show all the code for this part, if someone was going to help me.

Comment: How you call your `function Post` ??

Comment: with this:
    <?php
    Post();
    ?> in my create.php file

Comment: Try to pass post value in your `<?php Post($_POST); ?>` and in function use `function Post($data)` and use `$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $data['title']);`

Comment: You are using `category_id` in your query but in your table its `c_id`

Comment: @HarryBomrah i just used that in the post, since i didnt have enough space

Comment: @Saty still getting the same `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a nagging suspicion that your handling of `$category` as a string while `topic.category_id` is defined as `INT(11)` might be causing you grief. It would be worth changing your query to a prepared statement (for this and a multitude of other reasons) as follows:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO topic
    (category_id, user_id, title, body) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->link->prepare($query);
// The first arg, 'iiss', means "int, int, string, string"
$stmt->bind_param('iiss', $category, $_SESSION['id'], $title, $post_text);
$stmt->execute();
```

This allows the driver layer to automagically deal with quoting, escaping of special characters, and type-matching of data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: now it just says `Call to undefined method Database::prepare()`, can you give me the code for it, since i dont have it in my Database.php

Comment: Sorry, that should probably have been `$db->link->prepare()`. It's supposed to be the database link you created with `new mysqli()`.

Comment: Now this happens. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' `. I apologize for being a complete begginer

Comment: Well, that's closer than it was. ;) That just means there's something off in your `INSERT`. Stick in a `print_r($query)` before the call to `prepare()` to double-check your `INSERT` syntax.

Comment: This is what it says: `INSERT INTO topic (category_id, user_id, title, body) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)` when i added `print_r($query) a line before `$stmt = $db->link->prepare($query);`

Answer (score 1):

there is variable scope problem, 
please define

```
function Post()
{
    $title = ''; 
    $post_text = '';
    $category = '';
$db=new Database();

if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['title']);
$post_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['post_text']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['category']);
}
$query= "INSERT INTO topic
        (category_id, user_id, title, body) 
    VALUES('$category', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '$title', '$post_text')";

$insert_row = $db->insert($query);
}
```

Comment: that fixed the `undefined variable` problem, now i just get  the`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ` problem

Comment: this error states that , user user_id must present in your users table , than only you can insert data into your tpoics table

Comment: If you mean i wrote that in my question title, then yes. And you did give me a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Well i fixed it.

Turns out that in my html, in the option part i had it set to `<option value="<?php echo $category['name']`, instead of `<option value="<?php echo $category['id']`. I guess that when i set the button, it was looking for a string instead of an integer. Silly me