# How to fix prepared statement error

Tags: php, mysql

I use this statement to handle `$category_id` as an integer, instead of an string. Now i looked up how prepared statements need to be, and all seem correct to me,but when i execute the code i get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 247

This is the function i use the prepared statement in:

```
function Post($data)
{
$title = ''; 
$post_text = '';
$category = '';

$db=new Database();

if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $data['title']);
$post_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $data['post_text']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $data['category']);
}
$query= "INSERT INTO topic(category_id, user_id, title, body) 
      VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiss', $category, $_SESSION['id'], $title, $post_text);
$stmt->execute();
$insert_row = $db->insert($query);
}
```

Now although every other site says that my code is correct, i still get that my `query` is incorrect.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the `$insert_row = $db->insert($query);`. The `execute` should be executing the query. Also won't need to escape..

Comment: I think i need `$insert_row` to insert into the database right? Also yes i do need to escape since i got an error that says `Cannot add or update child row: Contraint foreign key`

Comment: That fixed it, i just removed the `$insert_row` variable and all works. Thank you

Comment: The `execute` sends the query. I don't know what your `insert` function does/did so hard to set what that variable was being used for/set to. The escaping won't fix that error..

Comment: No, you were right, the escaping doesnt fix it. It doesnt update my database

Comment: @Xy you should have led with your first comment. It is complaining because the `topic` table requires one or more of those values (most likely category_id and/or user_id) to reference values already present in other tables; and apparently one of the values you are attempting to use does not.

Comment: You should update this question, it isn't about the prepared statements. We'll need more information about your DB structure.

Comment: maybe this will help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014741/how-to-solve-undefined-variable-and-cannot-add-or-update-child-row. because my question here is answered.

Comment: I completely overlooked the `insert()` call in the other post. Derp.

Comment: I thought that i needed `insert()` to insert into my database, else i would have removed it instantly.